# How to select unique div id & remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I fetch posts from database with php while loop, Here is the e.g of HTML code->

```
<div id="1"> content <button class="btn-primary" data-id="1">button</button></div>
<div id="2">content 2 <button class="btn-primary" data-id="2">button</button></div>
```

if someone click on first button then div with id=1 should be removed

Here is the jquery code

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".btn-primary", function() {
        var ids = $(this).data('id'); // get data-id atrribute
        var elements = this;
        $('#id').remove(); // How can i remove the div by showing each id here
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.example.com/ajax,
            data: "ids=" + ids,
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.conner').append(data).fadeIn('slow');
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can Get div id dynamically and remove the div on click

Comment: `$('#' + ids).remove();` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless `data-id` holds several values you can:

```
var ids = $(this).data('id'); // get data-id atrribute
$('#' + ids).remove();
```

More simple way - is to remove a button parent:

```
$( this ).parent().remove();
```

Comment: i want to remove div by div id=" " not by data-id

Answer (score 1):

Either use the variable like :

```
$('#'+ids).remove();
```

Or you can simply go with

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Comment: I think the second option is the better one.

Answer (score 1):

If your container is always `div` you don't need to use ids you could just use :

```
$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it happend that if id of an element contains only number and we try to access that element with that id its creating problem soe better to use

`$(this).parent().remove();`

Answer (score 0):

If div which you want to delete is immediate parent of button than you can use,

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

If you have hierarchy than you can add `.parent()` multiple time like

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this ??

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/ZWjjZK?editors=1010)

```
$(".button1").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.div1').fadeOut(500);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1">content1
    <button class="btn-primary button1">button for div 1</button>
</div>
<div class="div1">content2
    <button class="btn-primary button1">button for div 2</button>
</div>
<div class="div1">content3
    <button class="btn-primary button1">button for div 3</button>
</div>
<div class="div1">content4
    <button class="btn-primary button1">button for div 4</button>
</div>
<div class="div1">content5
    <button class="btn-primary button1">button for div 5</button>
</div>
```